# What is the small signal gain for this circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, gain, common-emitter

The question looked easy at the first sight. I found the quiescent current through the BJTs.

I can say that |Vbe| = 0.7 V for both BJTs. Therefore, current through 1 kΩ below Q1 = 2 mA. Similarly, current through 0.7 kΩ above Q1 = 1 mA. So we can say current through Q1 and Q2 = 1 mA.

But for finding the gain, it's cascade common emitter with degeneration and common emitter. But then the 1 kΩ resistor is shared. Will that create any complication?

[image: CIRCUIT]

Comment: If the 1k was 40 Ohms it might be reasonably sinusoidal.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the fact that there's negative feedback caused by the connection between the emitter of Q1 and the collector of Q2.

Q1 is an emitter-follower, and the fact that it is "current boosted" by Q2 does not affect that. The overall gain is very close to unity.

The two transistors are connected as a [Sziklai pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair). Together, they function as a single NPN transistor that has a beta that is the product of the individual transistor betas. However, since beta was specified as infinity to begin with, this is effectively immaterial.

Comment: Oh I knew there was fundamentally something wrong . How can I do the calculation ? Its not just a emitter follower right ? I located the emitter follower , but how the whole circuit is primarily a emitter follower?

Comment: The emitter  cannot drive at unity gain with these Re RL values on the negative peaks.mIt can ONLY follow with pullup while the Re MUST pull down.

Comment: Tony is confused about the difference between "small signal" analysis and "large signal" analysis. In the former, we use DC analysis to determine the operating point, and then strictly linear AC analysis to determine the small-signal behavior. For that AC analysis, the 1K resistor is ignored, because it is completely overwhelmed by the 50-ohm load resistance.

Answer (score 1):

### This output load will not work with an AC coupled R smaller than Re

for a signal > 100 mV above the load current of Re*Ie. Vbe muThe output impedance for the attenuation becomes Rthev(base)/hFE (total) which is assumed infinite here but does no good if Re is not smaller than the AC coupled load.

This is a poor design and a unity gain is impossible.
This driver only “pushes” and the weak Re pulls down poorly.

The emitter resistor pulls down the output with a constant Vbe and adequate collector current.  This is not the case here.  (trick question)

The available drive current is emitter Ie=Ve/Re for DC current but with a 50 ohm AC coupled load, the it cannot pull down the emitter to charge the AC coupled load except for small signals of less than DC current.

So essentially the Vbe drops to 0 as the Re cannot pull down the base to drive the load current low.

So this becomes a horribly distorted amplifier.

Also this is not how to make a good 50 ohm driver but that’s another issue.

To fix this design, you must ensure DC current is enough to drive AC load current. Here Re=1k driving 50 =RL will never provide signal integrity and near unity gain.

### THUS ALWAYS ENSURE RL >= Re

Comment: Ok this is not a good model , this was a theory question in one previous year paper and this circuit looked strange and complex. Thank you

Comment: Not complex , just a design with unworkable  values and a common design fault, even overlooked by all the other experts here. right @jonk ?

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

> this was a theory question in one previous year paper

I see.

So you want to see how the circuit should be perceived through an appropriate small signal model.

But then, you cannot do that until you have worked through an appropriate DC large-scale model, because without the quiescent currents you cannot calibrate the small-signal model behavior.

And before any of that, I'm forced to waste time on using the schematic editor to get part numbering and so on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKnIS6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### DC Quiescent Point

Ignore \$I_{_{\text{C}_2}}\$ for now. Find base divider pair's \$V_{_{\text{TH}}}=2.7\:\text{V}\$ and \$R_{_{\text{TH}}}=1421\:\Omega\$ and then just solve via the usual KVL to find the emitter voltage as \$V_{_{\text{E}_1}}=\frac{V_{_{\text{TH}}}-\mid V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}\mid}{1+\frac{R_{_{\text{TH}}}}{\left(\beta+1\right)R_{_{\text{E}}}}}\approx 1.99\:\text{V}\$ and mentally note that this is about what we'd expect if we assumed \$\mid V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}\!\!\mid\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ at the outset. Besides, it's what the test question wants. So \$V_{_{\text{E}_1}}=2\:\text{V}\$ and we are done with that.

This says that \$I_{_{\text{R}_\text{E}}}= 2\:\text{mA}\$, but pushing that upward through \$R_{_{\text{C}}}\$ via \$Q_1\$ would yield a \$\mid V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}\!\!\mid\approx 1.4\:\text{V}\$ and we know that cannot be. So, just follow the test text and arbitrarily cut this back so that \$\mid V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}\!\!\mid\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ and finding that \$Q_1\$'s collector current must be \$1\:\text{mA}\$, and expect that \$Q_2\$'s collector is providing the residual bypass current of the other \$1\:\text{mA}\$.

From this, we'd project that \$I_{_{\text{C}_1}}=I_{_{\text{C}_2}}=1\:\text{mA}\$ and keep our values of \$\mid V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}\!\!\mid\:=\:\mid \!\! V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}\!\!\mid\:= 700\:\text{mV}\$.

Well, that's all the DC quiescent point analysis to be done here. It's just a test question, after all.

### Small-signal hybrid-\$\pi\$

You can quickly cobble up something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ZjpI.png)</sup>

You know, by their definition of \$V_T=25\:\text{mV}\$ and the above determination that both collector currents are \$I_{_{\text{C}_1}}=I_{_{\text{C}_2}}=1\:\text{mA}\$ that \$g_{m_1}=g_{m_2}=40\:\text{mS}\$. And, given \$\beta=\infty\$, I get \$A_{v_\text{O}}=\frac{R_{_{\text{E}}}}{R_{_{\text{E}}}+r_e^{\,'}}\cdot \left(1+40\:\text{mS}\cdot R_{_{\text{C}}}\right)=29\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{V}}\$ (if you discount \$r_e^{\,'}\$).

But that's open-loop and ignoring the negative feedback involved, being directly applied to the emitter of \$Q_1\$. In this case, the output into the emitter counters the base's motion, so the result is \$\left(v_{in}-v_{out}\right)\cdot 29=v_{out}\$, so I believe the closed loop gain is \$A_{v}=\frac{29}{1+29}=0.9\overline{6}\$.

That's my take.

Comment: Not possible for vo to load less the Re.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if my approach is exactly correct, please lemme know if there is any corrections required.

Ic1=Ic2=1mA

The gain due to Q1 =  -Rc1/(Re1+1/gm1) = 700/(1000+ 25)= -0.7 approx

Now gain due to Q2 = -Rc2*gm2 = -(50//1000)* 1/25= -2 approx

The total gain = 1.4

Comment: This design will not drive 50 Ohms and gain is always <=1 for this config., but nice try